# cannot run bash script in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have this bash script that I cannot seem to run in my dockerfile.
doing an ls -la shows the file being present

```
WORKDIR /opt/
RUN ls -la /opt
18:12:36  [AWS CodeBuild Plugin] #17 sha256:123456789
18:12:36  [AWS CodeBuild Plugin] #17 0.334 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root  root  23 May 17 17:12 build_script.run
```

But when I try and run it, it returns the following error:

```
RUN ./build_script.run
18:12:36  [AWS CodeBuild Plugin] #21 sha256:1234567890
18:12:36  [AWS CodeBuild Plugin] #21 0.541 /bin/sh: ./build_script.run: not found
```

what am I missing?

Comment: It's probably the 'shebang' executable specified on the first line of the script that is missing.

Comment: What's in your bash script. Specifically what does the shebang look like. Are you sure any shell specified in it exists at that path

Comment: The other thing that could cause this is if the script somehow got copied in with DOS line endings.  23 bytes (including the shebang line) is a _very_ short script; could you just move its contents directly into a Dockerfile `RUN` command?

Comment: Dumb question, I know, but just in case: that `WORKDIR /opt/` line is still there in the second variant, right?

Comment: @someone yes it is

Comment: @DavidMaze the script is actually massive so cant really do that

Comment: @TheWalkingMalteser have your checked the type of line endings for build_script.run? In my experience, Windows-style CRLF line endings is the most frequent cause for the error you're seeing, and it produces exactly your output.

Comment: And if that's not it, then please share the first line of your script with us.

Comment: @someone i ran a `cat -e build_script.run` and found that it has windows line endings. How can I run this?

Comment: @someone i ran dos2unix build_script.run and tried again, but ended with the same result